# how to use mysql "IFNULL"

Tags: mysql

As far as I know [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function is

IFNULL(exp1,exp2),when exp1=null will output exp2

but I try a some condition like as this

```
select  IFNULL (ams2.deptno.`FName`,'empty')
  from ams2.deptno as dept
```

but result still null not empty

I don't know where have problem,

have anyone can teach me how to fix?

Comment: If the result be not `empty` then does it look like a name?  Maybe the column simply isn't null?

Comment: is it possible that you have NULL stored  as a string in that column?

Comment: I'm sure the column default value is null ,

Comment: thank you guys,maybe I find my problem, let me to try

Comment: To debug, suggest trying `select ams2.deptno.FName is null from ...`. If the result is 1, stored value is really null. If the result is 0, you have a data value masquerading as a null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.The query You've used is correct need to debug can you give some other info like your table's crate table statement,some sample data

```
mysql> select ifnull(FName,'empty') as FName from deptno;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------   ---------------------------+
| FName                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------+
| myname                                                                                           |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| myname                                                                                         |
| empty                                                                                          |
| empty                                                                                          |
| empty                                                                                          |
| empty                                                                                          |
| empty                                                                                          |
| empty                                                                                            |
| iam                                                                                            |
| ifdsam                                                                                         |
| rwer
```

There are many other possible solutions which will fit your problem

1.Use the below Query

```
select COALESCE(ams2.deptno.`FName`,'empty') as dept 
from ams2.deptno
```

2.You can specify a default value for the column if the values are null

```
alter table ams2.deptno 
modify cloumn FName varchar(255) 
               not null default 'empty'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select  IFNULL(FName,'empty')
  from ams2.deptno;
```

Why dont you try this simple way without backticks, I tried its working.